# My C code won't compile against C code in a `.cu` file

Tags: cuda

I have 2 files that form a small CUDA library from my previous program (which works well, btw) written on C++.

The header for this library is:

```
     #ifndef __cudaLU__
     #define __cudaLU__

     #include <assert.h>
     #include <cuda_runtime.h>
     #include <cusolverDn.h>
     #include <cusolverSp.h>
     #include <cusparse.h>
     #include <cuComplex.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>


     void denseLS(int dim,
                  std::complex<float> * A,
                  std::complex<float> * b );

     void sparseLS(int dim,
                    std::complex<float> *csrVal,
                    int *csrRowPtr,
                    int *csrColInd,
                    std::complex<float> *vecVal);

     #endif
```

And I want to use this library in my old-as-the-hills C program just by setting procedure in the head of my main.c file:

```
     extern void denseLS(int dim, float complex *A, float complex *b);
```

And it fails with a bunch of similar errors. Few of them are:

```
     ..NA/cudaLS.cu(115): error: namespace "std" has no member "complex"

     ..NA/cudaLS.cu(115): error: expected a ")"

     ..NA/cudaLS.cu(137): error: identifier "csrRowPtr" is undefined

     ..NA/cudaLS.cu(169): error: identifier "csrColInd" is undefined

     ..NA/cudaLS.cu(170): error: identifier "csrVal" is undefined

     ..NA/cudaLS.cu(171): error: identifier "vecVal" is undefined
```

I tried to make a change std::complex -> float complex and nothing works. Still same errors (without std error, ofc).

The cmake instructions file

```
     cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
     project(NA)

     set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)



     find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
     find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

     include_directories("${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

     cuda_add_library(solvers STATIC
             cudaLS.cu
             cudaLS.h)

     target_link_libraries(solvers ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_cusolver_LIBRARY})
     target_compile_features(solvers PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
     set_target_properties( solvers
             PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)


     add_executable(NA main.c)
     set_target_properties(NA PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
     target_link_libraries(NA PRIVATE GSL::gsl m solvers)
```

What am I doing wrong pals?

UPD:

g++/gcc - 7.3

Linux

Comment: Err what? nvcc uses a C++ compilation by default. C versus C++ is not the source of your problem. For example I don't see where you imported <complex>

Comment: what is your OS and gcc version?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found what exactly I did in a wrong way.

Cmake is OK. But headers in the .h file have to be modified to

```
    extern "C" void denseLS(int dim, cuComplex *A, cuComplex *b );
```

The cuda functions in .c have to be decleared in the head (or separate .h-file) as

```
    void denseLS(int dim, float complex *A, float complex *b);
```

Comment: Why is the second definition different than the first one? Anyway, some of your error messages seem to have different reasons. I would suggest you consider removing this question.